# How to attach debugger to yarn start command

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have the following command `yarn start-package` with package being the project for package

I have configured the following launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Package Debuger",
            "preLaunchTask": "yarn start-package"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have configured the following tasks.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "yarn start-package",
            "type": "npm",
            "script": "start",
            "path": "packages/package",
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Now whenever i start debugger, it will never attach because the prelaunch task is starting the developing server and never finishes. How can i attach the debugger to the yarn start-package command correctly?

Note: I am using wsl for running the yarn command if it matters